# displaying images frame by frame in the same window in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I have three small images of same size. I want to display them one after another.

```
(define new1-bitmap 
(make-bitmap 
 (send bird-bitmap get-width) 
 (send bird-bitmap get-height)))

 (define dc-crop 
  (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap new1-bitmap]))

 (define f-crop 
  (new frame% [label "Random"]))
 (send f-crop show #t)

 (send dc-crop draw-bitmap-section 
    bird-bitmap 
            0 
            0 
            0 
            (round(* (/ (send bird-bitmap get-height) 3) 2)) 
            (send bird-bitmap get-width)
            (round(/ (send bird-bitmap get-height) 3)))
 (void 
  (new message% [parent f-crop] [label new1-bitmap]))
 (sleep 3)
 (send dc-crop draw-bitmap-section 
    new1-bitmap 
            0 
            0 
            0 
            (round(/ (send bird-bitmap get-height) 3)) 
            (send bird-bitmap get-width)
            (round(/ (send bird-bitmap get-height) 3)))
  (void 
  (new message% [parent f-crop] [label new1-bitmap]))
  (sleep 3)
  (send dc-crop draw-bitmap-section 
    new1-bitmap 
            0 
            0 
            0 
            0
            (send bird-bitmap get-width)
            (round(/ (send bird-bitmap get-height) 3)))
(void 
 (new message% [parent f-crop] [label new1-bitmap]))
```

Above is the code that I thought would work. It only take three images and tries to show them one after another at an interval of 3 seconds. Moreover the final GUI is three times longer than others.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple window with animation can be made using the 2htdp libraries. `2htdp/universe` is a handy place to start prototyping simple applications that mainly produce side effects.

The example code uses some of the icons that ship with Racket for convenience.

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image
         2htdp/universe)

(define image1 (bitmap icons/stop-16x16.png))
(define image2 (bitmap icons/bug09.png))
(define image3 (bitmap icons/break.png))

(define image-list (list image1 image2 image3))

(run-movie 3 image-list)
```

A more sophisticated example using `racket/gui` requires implementing a `timer%` rather than using `sleep` because [sleep acts on the thread level](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/threads.html?q=sleep#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sleep%29%29). It appears that when running directly from the source, Racket wants to queue both writes to the canvas then go to sleep and then empty the queue and make both writes in succession.

The second tricky bit is the nested send to access the canvas's drawing context.

The code example below is derived from [this thread on the Racket email list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.racket.user/796/match=canvas+hide). It displays an image of one of my current dogs, waits one second, then displays an image of one of my former dogs.

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)
(provide (all-defined-out))


(define image1 (make-object bitmap% "scarlett.jpg"))
(define image2 (make-object bitmap% "witty2.jpg"))
(define my-frame (instantiate frame%("my frame")))

(define mcan%
  (class canvas%
    (override  on-paint)
    (define on-paint
      (lambda()(send (send this get-dc)
                     draw-bitmap image1 0 0)))        
    (super-instantiate())))

(define mcan (new mcan% (parent my-frame)
                  (min-width (image-width image1))
                  (min-height (image-height image1))))

(define timer 
    (new timer%
         (notify-callback
          (lambda()
            (send (send mcan get-dc)
                  draw-bitmap image2 0 0)))))

(send my-frame show #t)
(send timer start 1000)
```

A third alternative is to use `sleep\yield` as described in [this post](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-July/063289.html) on the [Racket discussion list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/).